# how can i use AppStorage or UserDefaults to save data?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm fairly new to Swift and I'm creating a travel journal app. The user can add the place they traveled to, upload images, and write about their experiences.

I've been trying to get AppStorage or UserDefault to work on my app but when I close the app and return to it nothing is saved.

I've been writing different methods but nothing is working.

Here is my entire contentView.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm writing the AppStorage?

```
struct LandingView: View {

@AppStorage("name") var landingName: String?

@State private var oldLandingName: String = ""
@State private var newLandingName: String = ""

@State private var isAddingLanding = false
@State private var isSavingLanding = false

@State private var landings: [String] = []

@State private var isEditing = false

@State private var landingDetails: [String: [String]] = [:]
@State private var landingImages: [String: [Image]] = [:]
@State private var currentImages: [Image] = []

@State private var newLandingDetails: String = ""

@State private var isPresentingWriteView = false

@State private var selectedImage: UIImage?
@State private var displayedImage: Image? = nil
@State private var isPresentingImagePicker = false
@State private var selectedImages: [UIImage] = []

@State private var selectedImagesByLanding: [String: [UIImage]] = [:]

//@State private var travels: [Travel] = loadTravels()

@StateObject private var writeViewPresenter = WriteViewPresenter()

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

//@State private var savedContent: String = ""

@State private var isPresentingFullImage = false

//@State private var travels: [Travel] = loadTravels()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.yellow, Color.blue]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Add Your Travels")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        isAddingLanding = true
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                
                List(landings, id: \.self) { landing in
                    Text(landing)
                        .bold()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height: 20)
                        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                        .listRowBackground(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                .fill(
                                    LinearGradient(
                                        gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .white]),
                                        startPoint: .leading,
                                        endPoint: .trailing
                                    )
                                )
                                .padding(.vertical, 3)
                        )
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.isEditing = true
                            self.oldLandingName = landing
                            self.newLandingName = landing
                        }
                    
                    if let details = landingDetails[landing] {
                        ForEach(details, id: \.self) { detail in
                            Text(detail)
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if let images = selectedImagesByLanding[landing] {
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(images.prefix(3), id: \.self) { image in
                                Image(uiImage: image)
                                    .renderingMode(.original)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                    .padding(4)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        self.displayedImage = Image(uiImage: image)
                                        self.isPresentingFullImage = true
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isAddingLanding, onDismiss: {//saveTravels(travels)
        }) {
            ZStack {
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.blue, Color.yellow, Color.yellow]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            isAddingLanding = false
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        }
                        .padding(.leading, 20)
                        .frame(height: 20)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 80)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    TextField("Where did you go? \(newLandingName)", text: $newLandingName)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding()
                    
                    Button("Save") {
                        
                        if !newLandingName.isEmpty {
                            landings.append(newLandingName)
                            
                            if let images = selectedImagesByLanding[oldLandingName] {
                                        selectedImagesByLanding[oldLandingName] = []
                                        selectedImagesByLanding[newLandingName] = images
                                    } else {
                                        selectedImagesByLanding[newLandingName] = selectedImages
                                    }
                            
                            landingDetails[newLandingName] = []
                            
                            
                            selectedImages = []
                            
                            oldLandingName = ""
                            newLandingName = ""
                            newLandingDetails = ""
                            isAddingLanding = false
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 1)
                        
                Spacer()
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isEditing, onDismiss: {
        isAddingLanding = false
    }) {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.blue, Color.yellow, Color.yellow]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        newLandingName = ""
                        newLandingDetails = ""
                        isAddingLanding = false
                        
                        isEditing = false
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    TextField("", text: $newLandingName)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center) { _ in
                            return UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2
                        }
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button("Add Photos/Videos") {
                            isPresentingImagePicker = true
                        }
                        
                        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingImagePicker) {
                            ImagePicker(selectedImage: $selectedImage, sourceType: .photoLibrary) { image in
                                // Handle the selected image
                                if let image = image {
                                    selectedImages.append(image)
                                    ImageUploader().uploadImage(image) { result in
                                        switch result {
                                        case .success(let url):
                                            print("Image uploaded successfully. URL: \(url)")
                                        case .failure(let error):
                                            print("Image upload failed. Error: \(error)")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                isPresentingImagePicker = false
                            }
                        }
                        
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            isPresentingWriteView = true
                        }) {
                            Text("Write about it")
                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            isPresentingWriteView = true
                        }
                        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentingWriteView) {
                            NavigationView {
                                WriteView(text: $newLandingName, isPresented: $isPresentingWriteView)
                                    .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                                    .navigationBarItems(
                                        leading:
                                            Button(action: {
                                                isEditing = false
                                                isPresentingWriteView = false
                                            }) {
                                                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                                                    .imageScale(.large)
                                            }
                                    )
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(selectedImages, id: \.self) { image in
                                Image(uiImage: image)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                    .padding(4)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        //selectedImages.append(image)
                                        self.displayedImage = Image(uiImage: image)
                                        self.isPresentingFullImage = true
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingFullImage) {
                        if let displayedImage = displayedImage {
                            VStack {
                                Spacer()
                                
                                displayedImage
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                Button(action: {
                                    self.isPresentingFullImage = false
                                }) {
                                    Text("Close")
                                        .padding()
                                        .background(
                                            LinearGradient(
                                                gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .white]),
                                                startPoint: .leading,
                                                endPoint: .trailing
                                            )
                                        )
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        .cornerRadius(10)
                                    
                                }
                                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                            }
                            .background(Color.black)
                            .ignoresSafeArea()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $writeViewPresenter.isPresented) {
                    WriteView(text: $newLandingName, isPresented: $writeViewPresenter.isPresented)
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    // Handle save action here
                    if !newLandingName.isEmpty {
                        if !landings.contains(newLandingName) {
                            landings.append(newLandingName)
                            selectedImagesByLanding[newLandingName] = selectedImagesByLanding[oldLandingName] ?? []
                        }
                        
                        if let details = landingDetails[newLandingName] {
                            if !newLandingDetails.isEmpty {
                                landingDetails[newLandingName]?.append(newLandingDetails)
                            }
                        } else {
                            if !newLandingDetails.isEmpty {
                                landingDetails[newLandingName] = [newLandingDetails]
                            }
                        }
                        
                        if let index = landings.firstIndex(of: oldLandingName) {
                            landings.remove(at: index)
                        }
                        
                        if let images = selectedImagesByLanding[oldLandingName] {
                            selectedImagesByLanding[newLandingName] = images
                        }
                        selectedImagesByLanding[newLandingName] = selectedImages
                        
                        
                        newLandingName = ""
                        isAddingLanding = false
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Save")
                }
                
                
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you actually use or set landingName?

Comment: Note that UserDefaults is not meant to persist data. You should only use it to preserve the UI state. If you need to persist data locally take a look at Codable protocol and Application Support Directory. Another option but probably a bit more complex to beginners is Core Data. There is also a new framework called SwiftData for SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the landingName var somewhere in your code.

Here is a working simplified example with a more description storage name:

```
struct LandingView: View {
    @AppStorage("appLandingName") var landingName: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let landingName = landingName {
                Text(landingName)
            }
            
            Button("Change Landing Name") {
                landingName = "Name \(Int.random(in: 1..<1000))"
            }
        }
    }
}
```